# UDP port is not free after closesocket call (Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, udp

I have two listening sockets (created by calls to `socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)`), at this moment they are maintained from one thread.

After creating, they have to be closed (`closesocket(...)`) and reopened again on the same ports. But `bind(...)` call returns error 10048 `WSAEADDRINUSE` on one of these sockets (the second one is opened successfully), and I see by using `netstat` that the UDP port stays open (`closesocket(...)` returned no error, `SO_REUSEADDR` always set to TRUE on all sockets). And this "closed" UDP port stays open as long as the 2nd socket is open (they have no relation, but the "closed" port is closing a second after the 2nd socket is closed).

Let's summarize:

1. Open sockets and bind them to ports 8888 and 9999.
2. Close 8888 socket, create new socket, bind it to port 8888 -> success.
3. Close 9999 socket, create new socket, and try to bind it to port 9999 -> error `WSAEADDRINUSE`.
4. Close 8888 socket -> success.
5. After about a second after #4, port 9999 is freed (by observing in external tool).

I have discovered something similar to my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26129726/10101917, but in my case moving all socket operations to one thread does not solve the problem.

What is happening here?

Comment: Please try to create a proper [mre] to show us. A description just doesn't give us enough context and details.

Comment: "*After creating they have to be closed and reopened again on the same ports*" - why?  UDP is connection-less. There is no need to open new sockets on the old ports, just reuse the old sockets.

Comment: Related, possible dupe: [How to close Winsock UDP socket hard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634904/)

Comment: @RemyLebeau actually I have a library which has old UDP protocol but now must support MsQuic protocol. I'm first starting to receive UDP packets, using old protocol, but if I recognize QUIC header I am deleting old listener object and create MsQuic listener object, which reports this error. I have actually tried to create a simple UDP socket instead of MsQuic, which reports this error too.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Still have no luck create minimal example, maybe this is related to DLL. Because my original code is DLL, but I am trying to reproduce it in simple application...

Comment: @VladTishenko Closing a socket port is not instantaneous, there are some delays involved. But unless `SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE` is being used, then `SO_REUSEADDR` should work fine. Without a [mcve], there is no way for anyone here to diagnose what is really happening. Are you *sure* that some other process is not using port 9999? What does `netstat` say when the error happens?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Actually I have just discoverd that MsQuic internally uses SIO_ACQUIRE_PORT_RESERVATION, and error happens when this WSAIoctl(SocketProc->Socket, SIO_ACQUIRE_PORT_RESERVATION...) call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what caused this problem. The thing I have programmed is the DLL. I have discovered, that another DLL from this app is using QProcess class of Qt library version 5.7.1. I have checked sources of Qt and discovered that this class actually starts process with bInheritHandles set to TRUE. When I manually have reset this value to FALSE all issues were gone.

It is obvious that the issue was caused by the following: one of UDP socket handles was inherited by child process and that process didn't let socket handle to be closed, until that process stop.

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71552970/udp-socket-not-unbinding-from-a-port?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment126545142_71552970) comment for pointing to the solution.